# QGIS Segmentation fault when manipulating QgsGeometry

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

So I am running QGIS 2.8.1 on Ubuntu 14.04. This following problem is happening in my script, but also occurs directly in the QGIS python console:

```
lay = iface.activeLayer()
lay.featureCount()
1L
lay.type()
0
prov = lay.dataProvider()
prov.geometryType()
3
geom = lay.getFeatures().next().geometry()
geom
<qgis._core.QgsGeometry object at 0x7fff4d5f90e8>
```

Next, if I do pretty much anything with that QgsGeometry object I get a dizzying array of Segmentation faults. I noticed it first when I was trying to intersection tests with other geometries, but even simple calls like geom.type() results in :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffefe0c3ca in _int_free (av=0x0, p=0x5042970, have_lock=0)
at malloc.c:3943
```

but mostly it has to do with the GEOS related functions:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff123798f in GEOSGeom_destroy_r () from /usr/lib/libgeos_c.so.1
```

is this a known bug? http://hub.qgis.org/issues/777

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced this in QGIS 2.14.2 on Ubuntu, both in Console and in a saved .py script.

[The issue you linked to](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/777) has the answer - change your call from `.geometry()` to `.geometryAndOwnership()`. I tried that and it fixes the problem.

According to the API docs this method is deprecated and you should use `constGeometry()` instead - but I find this also segfaults.

From the issue, it seems the feature object is 'lost' by the time it gets to your `.type()` call, and it's taken the geometry with it. You might also be able to get around this by assigning things one at a time, rather than by method chaining, <s>but not tried this</s>.

**EDIT**

I tried unrolling the method chaining - this works.

```
lay = iface.activeLayer()
print lay.featureCount()
print lay.type()
prov = lay.dataProvider()
print prov.geometryType()
features = lay.getFeatures()
nextfeature = features.next()
geom = nextfeature.geometry()
print geom
print geom.getType()
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm and, I suppose, it will be also work when the API moves to 3.0. (unlike constGeometry)

Comment: Actually it will also be removed for 3.0. there'll be a single . geometry() getter and .setGeometry(...) setter. Either way, you'll need to update code.

Answer (score 5):

It's a known issue, which will be fixed when QGIS moves to QGIS 3.0 development (since the fix could potentially break existing plugins).

To work around it, you need to force a copy of the geometry:

```
geom = QgsGeometry( lay.getFeatures().next().geometry() )
```

**Technical explanation below:**

Calling just

```
geom = lay.getFeatures().next().geometry()
```

results in a reference to a "temporary" geometry (a c++ object), which will go out of scope and be deleted together with its owner feature (ie, the QgsFeature returned by `lay.getFeatures().next()`). Since you're not keeping a reference to the feature itself around, it will get garbage collected almost immediately by python and its geometry will be deleted too. Making a copy of the geometry by using `QgsGeometry(...)` will result in a geometry which python has full ownership over and will be correctly kept around for the required lifetime of the python object.

**Explanation of constGeometry()**

Note that it's more efficient to use `feature.constGeometry()` in place of `feature.geometry()`. Behind the scenes (in the c++ code), calling `feature.geometry()` can sometimes force a full copy of the feature to be made, which is expensive. Calling instead `feature.constGeometry()` will never make this unnecessary copy.

(All this mess is scheduled to be cleaned up for QGIS 3.0!)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Can't wait for 3.0, when all our problems will be solved! ;)  constGeometry was added in 2.9 and I'm running 2.8.1. Unchaining the method calls worked for me as @steven-kay suggested.