# Why QGIS crashes when constructing QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer object by QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.createRenderer() method?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, rendering, vector-layer

Today I want to render a vector layer in QGIS by using PyQGIS `QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer` renderer. When I directly construct it by using the constructor, it works. But when I want to use the `createRenderer()` method, QGIS then crashed unexpectedly. I have executed my code in QGIS 3.14.0 and QGIS 3.16.3 python console and QGIS crashed all. I want to know if there is a problem in my code or a bug with QGIS.

Here is the code:

```
LayerPath = r"C:\Users\15239\Desktop\QGIS\dln.gpkg"
DelaunayLayer = QgsVectorLayer(LayerPath,"Delaunay","ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(DelaunayLayer)
CpyRamp = QgsCptCityColorRamp("cb/div/BrBG_","05")
SimpleSymbol = QgsFillSymbol([QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer(QColor(0,50,70))])
DelaunayLayer.setRenderer(QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.createRenderer(DelaunayLayer,'AREA',5,1,SimpleSymbol,CpyRamp))
DelaunayLayer.triggerRepaint()
```

Here are the test data and its attribute table:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem in your code or no bug with QGIS. `createRenderer` method is [deprecated since v3.10](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.html#af93c5eda26ff7be7f31ffde4c4bb14c1). Therefore, there may be incompatibility between the method and later versions of QGIS. I recommend you use the constructor.

Comment: qgis.org/api is down now, I guess. Use [google cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:duufdzSHdwsJ:https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't notice the `Q_DECL_DEPRECATED` identifier of this method in QGIS API Documentation.  :-)

Comment: Though some python crashes may be caused by c++ and python not playing well together. I can't find the link back but the two style of management of python and c++. Meaning that you need to be more careful in python.

Comment: No, this is actually about object ownership and references. If the method did not exist or is deprecated, QGIS does not crash but shows/logs an error.

Comment: @bugmenot123 Thank you for clarification. You say this answer is wrong?

Comment: "Wrong" in that it suggests search for a workaround (that probably would crash the same) and does not really answer the question :D See my answer with restructured, working code. Sadly I could not find what method is recommended as alternative to the deprecated one.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the crash is that you create intermediate C++ objects that are already not "existing" anymore when you try to use them. Or something like that, I am not 100% sure myself.

Nyall Dawson wrote some explanation in an older answer to an unrelated issue: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/192202/51035

The gist is that if you work with QGIS' objects, it often is a good idea to assign names to them so no garbage collector removes them in the wrong moment. You might still run into issues if objects chance in the background but it is much reduced.

This should work without crashes:

```
...
CpyRamp = QgsCptCityColorRamp("cb/div/BrBG_","05")
SymbolLayer = QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer(QColor(0,50,70))
SimpleSymbol = QgsFillSymbol([SymbolLayer])
Renderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.createRenderer(DelaunayLayer,'AREA',5,1,SimpleSymbol,CpyRamp)
DelaunayLayer.setRenderer(Renderer)
...
```

FYI using `CamelCase` for names is highly discouraged. Standard format for Python names is `snake_case`.

Comment: I'm not a C++ expert. I'm just trying to understand. What part doesn't exist when **it** is used? There are a lot of similar usages in PyQGIS. What makes **it** special?

Comment: Me too! I added a link to an older answer from Nyall.

Comment: Did you test it without crash?

Comment: Yes of course! :) You can try with the world easter egg and then `DelaunayLayer  = iface.activeLayer()`.